# PHP MySQL Update dateTime in database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm actually working on project which will look like an auction system. Im struggling with one problem since few days.

Main idea is: when you are on the page with the overview of the product, there is a countdown timer, which shows how much time left for this item to bid on it. Then, if user clicks "Add bid", I'm taking coins from his account, and then trying to update time to "actual ending time + 1 hour" (for example).

I cant figure out how can I update database record with dateTime type column with for example 1 hour. Right now the code looks as below:

```
$finalDate2DB = "";
$addedTime = strtotime('1 hour');

$finalDate2DB = date($finalDate + $addedTime); // $finalDate variable is holding the date from database (for example 2018-01-21 18:02:48)
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE items SET endTime = :finalDate2DB WHERE itemID = :itemID");

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':itemID' => $itemID,
    ':finalDate2DB' => $finalDate2DB
));
```

When I click to add bid, then in database endTime (column) changes its value to "0000-00-00 00:00:00" instead of the date which was before there + 1 hour.

Wish someone could give at least any tip, as I'm struggling with this one for really long time...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
$hour_later = strtotime($finalDate) + 60*60;
$finalDate2DB = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , $hour_later);
```